Determine TLB size on ARM64 (Linux)
For Intel there's cpuid command that can report TLB levels, sizes, associativity, etc. Is there a way to do the same on ARM64?

Outsource it to the OS? e.g. proc/cpuinfo on Linux?

Sorry, I forgot to add OS (Linux); as for me there's nothing on caches on ARM in /proc/cpuinfo, I'm running 5.10 kernel
